Returning a subset of a nested dictionary - Returns None
I'm trying to create a function that take a nested dictionary and returns a subset/item depending on the path provided as an ordered tuple. I'm using a circular reference of the function to iterate over the nested dictionary as follow.
my_dict = 
{
    "nested_1": {
        "nested_1_1": {
            "nested_1_1_1": "item_1_2",
            "nested_1_1_2":{
                "nested_1_1_2_1": "item_1_1_1_1"
            }
        },
        "nested_1_2": "item_1_2"
    }
}

def retrieve_nested_dict(nested_dict:dict, keys):
    if len(keys) == 1:
        dict_var = nested_dict[keys[0]]
        return dict_var
    else:
        key = keys[0]
        if key in nested_dict:
            retrieve_nested_dict(nested_dict[key], keys[1:])
        else:
            print(f'{key} is not a valid key')

retrieve_nested_dict(my_dict, ('nested_1', 'nested_1_1', 'nested_1_1_2'))

This should return {"nested_1_1_2_1": "item_1_1_1_1"}
retrieve_nested_dict(my_dict, ('nested_1', 'nested_1_1'))
This should return {"nested_1_1_1": "item_1_2", "nested_1_1_2":{"nested_1_1_2_1": "item_1_1_1_1"}}
but I keep getting back None. It seems that the function doesn't exit immediately after the return statement, but I don't understand why.
Anyone can point what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks

I think retrieve_nested_dict(nested_dict[key], keys[1:]) should be return retrieve_nested_dict(nested_dict[key], keys[1:])

There's no need to use recursion for this, you can just do it with a for loop.

for key in keys: nested_dict = nested_dict[key]

Basically every call that eventually reaches if len(keys) == 1 needs to return the value of the previous call.
